# Convert URL to AbsolutePath

Tags: java, url, file-io

Is there any easy way to convert a URL that contains to two-byte characters into an absolute path?

The reason I ask is I am trying to find resources like this:

```
URL url=getClass().getResources("/getresources/test.txt");
String path=url.toString();
File f=new File(path);
```

The program can't find the file. I know the path contain '%20' for all spaces which I could convert but my real problem is I'm using a japanese OS and when the program jar file is in a directory with japanese text (for example デスクトップ) I get the [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of the directory name,
like this:

%e3%83%87%e3%82%b9%e3%82%af%e3%83%88%e3%83%83%e3%83%97

I think I could get the UTF-8 byte codes and convert this into the proper characters to find the file, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

nt

Comment: That isn't "garbage."  Those are escaped representations of characters. They are legitimate values. The reason why your code fragment does not work is because Class.getResources and File have different root spaces.

Comment: Is there class i can use to convert the path to normal readable characters?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/getresources/test.txt");
File f = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: thx, as i was saying below, this only works in netbeans. when i compile the app i run into an error.

Comment: Moritz got it. A File object cannot instantiate using a URL to an archived resource. You'll have to stream it.

Comment: got an exception "URI is not hierarchical"

Answer (score 23):

If you were interested in getting [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) from URL, you can do:

```
Path p = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

Comment: Since Java 11, one may use `Path#of` instead of `Paths#get`.

Answer (score 10):

`File` has a constructor taking an argument of type `java.net.URI` for this case:

```
File f = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: I tried this. When I run the program in Netbeans it works, but when a build it is doesn't work.

Comment: The error I'm getting is:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

Comment: Could it be that you are bundling your app with the resources in a `.jar`-file? You cannot create a `File` object from that `URI` then as the resource is not a file but an entry in that `.jar`.

Comment: Ah I see. So since I am bundling it in a .jar file, is there any solution here?

Comment: No. You would have to read from the resource through an `InputStream` either by calling `url.openStream()` or directly via `getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource.txt")`. If you need to know where on disk your `.jar` is you can inspect the `URL` returned but you cannot create a `File` referencing your resource inside that `.jar`.

Answer (score 6):

Another option for those who use Java 11 or later:

```js
Path path = Path.of(url.toURI());
```

or as a string:

```js
String path = Path.of(url.toURI()).toString();
```

Both methods above throw a `URISyntaxException` that can be safely ignored if the URL is guaranteed to be a file URL.