# How to convert a Java File URI inot a absolute path?

Tags: java

I have a situation in which I receive a File URI in the format

```
file:///home/user/a.txt
```

I know that depending of the operation system other formats can be expected:

```
file:/C:/a.txt            <- On Windows
file:///C:/a.txt          <- On Windows
file:///home/user/a.txt   <- On Linux
```

I need the absolute file path to store the file. So I want to convert:

```
file:///home/user/a.txt   ===>   /home/user/a.txt
```

I do now this in a very clumsy way:

```java
    public void save(URI targetURI) {
        Path path = Paths.get("/", targetURI.toString()).normalize();
        String filePath=""+path;
        filePath=filePath.replace("/file:", "");
    ....
    }
```

I expect there is a more elegant solution based on the java.io util classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this -> [Convert URL to AbsolutePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631623/convert-url-to-absolutepath)

```
Path p = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

and how say @GOTO 0

> Another option for those who use Java 11 or later:
>
> Path path = Path.of(url.toURI()); or as a string:
>
> String path = Path.of(url.toURI()).toString(); Both methods above
> throw a URISyntaxException that can be safely ignored if the URL is
> guaranteed to be a file URL.

**UPDATE**

And i found this -> https://eed3si9n.com/encoding-file-path-as-URI-reference/
The solution to the problem is described in great detail here

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException
{
    URI uri = new URI("file:/C:/a.txt");
    save(uri);

    uri = new URI("file:///C:/a.txt");
    save(uri);

    uri = new URI("file:///home/user/a.txt");
    save(uri);

}

public static void save(URI targetURI)
{
    Path p = Paths.get(targetURI);
    String absolutePath = p.toString();
    System.out.println(absolutePath);
}
```

Comment: But my source element is a java.net.URI and not a java.net.URL

Comment: @Ralph I`m updated answer

Comment: @Ralph If the question is closed, then fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

ok, quite simple

```java
public void save(URI targetURI) {
   Path p=Paths.get(targetURI).toString());
   String absolutePath= p.toString();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes.  But there should be no toString in the first line.  It’s just `Path p = Paths.get(targetURI);`.